# Javascript Code Process Flow (function within function)

Tags: javascript

So my issue is, I have recently learned that javascript allows you to define a function within another function. However, I notice that such functions within other functions are not always explicitly called. Given this example,

```
function main()
{
  function f1()
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

will f1 execute automatically as the main function executes? Does it matter where inside main f1 is defined (beginning or end)? What are the general rules when dealing with functions within other functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not automatically executed and is only available within the scope of the outer function, so you don't have access to `f1` outside `main`, unless it has been exposed by some other means. To execute `f1`, invoke it in code.

```
function main() {
    function f1() { .. }
    f1(); // calling f1
}
```

If the function is a Function Declaration, then you can use it anywhere within the function, even before it is defined. If it is a Function Expression, then it can only be used after it has been defined. Consider what happens if we try to use a function expression before it is defined,

```
function main() {
    f1();  // TypeError: undefined is not a function
    var f1 = function() { }; // Function Expression
}
```

If it was a function declaration, this would have worked,

```
function main() {
    f1(); // No errors
    function f1() { }; // Function Declaration
}
```

There are subtle rules on when a function is an Expression vs a Declaration, and this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) on function scopes may be helpful.

Comment: `function f1() { };` is a function **declaration** (copy&paste error? ;))

Answer (score 0):

In this example, `f1` is only defined, not called. It will be executed only if called or assigned to some field/variable to be called later.

As for location, it can be defined anywhere -- function definitions are always the first thing to be discovered in the scope, even if they are defined at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Now f1 is *automatically* executed and changes `a`:

```
function main(){
  var a = 1;
  (function f1(){
    a = 2;
  })()
  alert(a)  // 2
}
```

Try out: http://jsfiddle.net/4kuJM/1/